# remove some of the list tags using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have list of tags I want to remove some of the list tags and repopulate them with different values. I have

```
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Selected</a></li>
         <c:forEach var="category" items="${selectedCats}">
           <li><a href="#">${category.value.name}</a>
           <a href="#" >selected</a></li>
         </c:forEach>
     </ul>
```

So, I want to remove everything inside for loop and want to repopulate it in jquery.

Comment: Do you want to repopulate using jquery ajax ?
Can you please explain it more briefly.

Comment: I don't understand why this question clsoed and what is not clear here .Two people have already understood it with in an hour and I accepted  the answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some dummy class name in loop li items for identification and remove it.

```
   <c:forEach var="category" items="${selectedCats}">
       <li class="new-item"><a href="#">${category.value.name}</a>
       <a href="#" >selected</a></li>
     </c:forEach>
```

Then remove

```
 $('li.new-item').remove();
```

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.fn.remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove one, or more elements from the DOM.

```
$('li.item').remove();
```

... and [$.fn.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) in order to add new content.

```
$("ul#my-list").append("<li>A new entry</li>");
```